# using multiprocessing to send/receive system calls

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm new to Python multiprocessing, but use Python quite alot. I use python for
scripting system calls to different programs many times (instead of shell scripting).

Lets say I have a computing cluster with 64 processors, and I need to run an os.system call to call an external program many times over and over, each being expensive.

Is there a way to use multiprocessing to loop around my systemcalls?

Lets say I have the following loop:

I have a list of appropriate filenames.

```
for i in filenames:

         ...code to setup new protein system.. 
         os.system("$AMBERHOME/exe/sander -O -i min3.in -o min3.out -p test.prmtop -c test.inpcrd -r min3.rst -ref test.inpcrd")
```

basically my code scripts setting up a protein system and then running the amber program on the new system over and over again. It does this in serial, and takes a lot of time since if there are 200 structures, for each structure when it calls amber it can take 30 minutes, so total runtime is 30*200 minutes.

What I'd like, if possible, is to use the 64 processors-- perhaps a way (or a reference to something where I can try to implement a way) for me to use multiprocessing in Python so that when I have 64 processors, I can go through the above loop in a way so that an individual processor is each used for 64 independent processes (the os.system command) at a time, and when each one completes, it sends some signal to continue the loop for the next available structure. Maybe some way of 1 of the processors keeping track of the other processors doing the work (via the os.system calls).

Is this something that is possible to implement in python using multiprocessing on a cluster? If anyone can suggest an approach, or a useful reference to look into to be able to tackle this, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look [pydra](http://code.osuosl.org/projects/pydra)

Comment: I think I've printed out every possible thing related to this question today using multiprocessing/threading etc. I think the best way to do something like this is to use mpi4py. It took me quite a bit to figure out how to get working, but now that its working I can use that to farm my tasks effectively. Thanks for the pointer to pydra!